# How to show a red stat panel in Grafana if a metric value > T or the data is unavailable?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Currently I show the state of a container in Grafana using:

`time() - container_last_seen{name="my_X_container_name"}`

Using a Stat panel, I set the color to red if the elapsed time is greater than my sample rate.

However, how do I handle the case where the data is unavailable because the container with the name 'my_X_container_name' never started?

How would I update the Grafana Stat panel so that it is red if either:

- the data is unavailable
- elapsed time is too high (>T)

Should I be using the method 'absent' and or 'unless' ?

(I'm using cadvisor to monitor my containers, and Prometheus to monitor metrics, and Grafana to display data).

Comment: Go to panel options and add value mapping: Null -> 'Never started', 'red'.

Comment: @markalex I did add a 'Null' mapping, but it seems to take just the Threshold color from Base. So I set Base to a red color, and set '0' to green.

Answer (score -1):

Set the Base threshold color to red, and add a threshold value '0' and set to green.